# reinstalling Chrome on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-chrome

Lately my debugger (xdebug) running in phpStorm is popping up a message that I need to update Chrome. But when i try this I get a message "chrome is out of date", can't update chrome, reinstall chrome. When I click on the button to reinstall chrome I get this link https://www.google.com/chrome/?&brand=CHWL&utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-et-na-us-chrome-bubble&utm_medium=et .

I click the reinstall button I get a popup asking "Note: Installing Google Chrome will add the Google repository so your system will automatically keep Google Chrome up to date. If you don’t want Google's repository, do “sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome” before installing the package."

There is no explanation. Do I want to add the google respository?
Sorry for the caution but more than once I followed directions I didn't really understand and it led to my laptop getting totally screwed up.

Now, I found this on the chrome site: Linux users: **To update Google Chrome, use your package manager.**

Are there any directions for this???

update: I tried this. I seem to be stuck here. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this command:

```bash
sudo apt install --reinstall google-chrome-stable
```